# Meta package for Ubuntu Gnome Edition?

Tags: gnome

All other editions have meta packages, e.g. xubuntu-desktop, is there such package for Ubuntu Gnome Edition? If not, what's the best way of replicating Ubuntu Gnome experience having a standard Unity 14.04 install?

Comment: Enable the Univers repository if you don't find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is, as can be expected, called [`ubuntu-gnome-desktop`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/ubuntu-gnome-desktop). I assume there is also a task with the same name.